# How to check file type on input type file change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io

I have a form that uploads file with ajax, the file selection event is like this:

```
# This JS is translated directly from coffeescript

$("input[name=dump_file]").on('change', function() {
  # if not .xls do something like window.alert
  # else
  var dump_file;
  return dump_file = this.files[0];
});
```

I need to check if `dump_file` is in excel format (.xls or .xlsx), how to check for `this.files[0]` file type on `change` event?

Comment: So read the value and check the value...

Comment: how do i read and check the value? (in JS) @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

Check the file `type` included on the file object:

```
if (this.files[0].type == "xls/xlsx") { //not sure if that's the right type, you'll have to log it first
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: that returns `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

I've found solution using this though: `this.files[0].name.split(".").pop()`

Comment: The above only applies is the file has a single "." in it.